# requests - Python command line behavior differs from behavior when script is run

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script that will input data I supply into a web form at a url I supply.

To start with, I'm testing it out by simply getting the html of the page and outputting it as a text file. (I'm using Windows, hence .txt.)

```
import sys
import requests

sys.stdout = open('html.txt', 'a')

content = requests.get('http://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html')

content.text
```

When I do this (i.e., the last two lines) on the python command line (>>>), I get what I expect. When I do it in this script and run it from the normal command line, the resulting html.txt is blank. If I add `print(content)` then html.txt contains only: <Response [200]>.

Can anyone elucidate what's going on here? Also, as you can probably tell, I'm a beginner, and I can't for the life of me find a beginner-level tutorial that explains how to use requests (or urllib[2] or selenium or whatever) to send data to webpages and retrieve the results. Thanks!

Comment: The interactive interpreter always displays the return value of any expression you enter into it - that's why it's also referred to as a [REPL (Read Eval Print Loop)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). That's a special behavior of the interactive interpreter that regular scripts don't exhibit. If you want to display a value in a script, you'll have to explicitly `print` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
import sys
import requests

result = requests.get('http://www.york.ac.uk/teaching/cws/wws/webpage1.html')
if result.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    with open('html.txt', 'a') as sys.stdout:
        print result.content
```

Requests returns an instance of type `request.Response`. When you tried to print that, the `__repr__` method was called, which looks like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Response [%s]>' % (self.status_code)
```

That is where the `<Response [200]>` came from.

The `requests.Reponse` has a `content` attribute which is an instance of `str` (or `bytes` for Python 3) that contains your HTML.

The `text` attribute is type `unicode` which may or may not be what you want. You mention in the comments that you saw a `UnicodeDecodeError` when you tried to write it to a file. I was able to replace the `print result.content` above with `print result.text` and I did not get that error.

If you need help solving your `unicode` problems, I recommend reading this [unicode presentation](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/). It explains why and when to decode and encode `unicode`.

Comment: I added a note about why it worked. If you need more information let me know.

Comment: So my arbitrary choice of "content" as a variable name was also a problem?

Comment: No. You were trying to print `content.text` to the file, which is `unicode` and caused the `UnicodeDecodeError`. The `content` attribute is already ASCII.

Comment: @MarcAdler no, that wasn't the issue. What you called `content` and David named `result` is a `Response` object. It has two main ways to access the response body, the properties `Response.content` and `Response.text`. `content` returns a bytestring (for binary data, or textual data in its original encoding), and `text` returns `unicode` (the decoded response body according to HTTP headers and/or some characer set detection).

Answer (score 2):

The interactive interpreter *echoes* the result of every expression that doesn't produce `None`. This doesn't happen in regular scripts.

Use `print` to explicitly echo values:

```
print response.content
```

I used the *undecoded* version here as you are redirecting stdout to a file with no further encoding information.

You'd be better of writing the output directly to a file however:

```
with open('html.txt', 'ab') as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(response.content)
```

This writes the response body, undecoded, directly to the file.

Comment: I actually tried that, and it didn't work. I got "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode..." yada yada.

Comment: @MarcAdler: you didn't specify your Python version, since you `response.text` I assumed Python 3. For Python 2, stick to `response.content` when printing too.